# Создать директорию при первой записи в файл python

Tags: python

Допустим мы хотим записать некую информацию в файл.

Файл должен располагаться в определенной директории.

При этом, если информация, например, не найдена, то и в файл она не записывается и, соответственно, не создается для этого файла отдельная директория.

Вот попытка сделать это с помощью `pathlib`.

```
from pathlib import Path

file = Path('output/info.txt')
file.open('w')
```

Это, очевидно, вызывает ошибку `FileNotFoundError`.

Вот функция, которая у меня получилась:

```
from pathlib import Path

dir = Path('res/test.txt')

def open_new(path: Path):
    path.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    path.touch(exist_ok=True)
    return path.open('w', encoding='utf8')

with open_new(dir) as f:
    f.write('info...')
```

Возможно кому-то будет полезно.

Comment: так а вопрос-то в чем? какая информация может быть "не найдена". например?

Comment: Проверить наличие каталога и создать его, если его нет             if not os.path.isdir('output'):
                    os.makedirs('output', 0o755)

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/50110800/10562663

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из ответа на [английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50110841/8324991):

```
pathlib.Path('/tmp/sub1/sub2').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

То есть в вашем случае:

```
from pathlib import Path

fdir = Path('output')
fdir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
file = fdir / 'info.txt'
with open(file, 'w') as f:
    ...
```

Comment: Это очень близко.
Я говорил про что-то подобное, только данный код не работает, все равно.
from pathlib import Path

dir = Path('res/test.txt')

def open_new(path: Path):
    path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    return path.open('w', encoding='utf8')

with open_new(dir) as f:
    f.write('info...')

В конечном счете функция принимает путь до файл и сама прокладывает директорию и создает файл, при необходимости.